# Check if cookie data is an array

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am passing ID's to a cookie on each click of a product on my site.

Each click will push the new id's to the existing cookie value, creating an array.

This is the basics of my cookie setting code, followed by the current value after a few clicks:

```
var cookieArray = [];

cookieArray.push('582');
```

Example after I clicked 3 products. 582, 590 and 572

`[582%2C590%2C572]`

**My question:** Is the format of my cookie value correctly an array? Considering the `%2C` separating each ID?

I will be grabbing the data later with PHP and looping through each value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%2` is a comma (`,`), so yes, if you stringify a JS array and then encode it, that's what you get.

You can use PHP's [`unserialize`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) to parse it.

You could also store JSON in your cookies an then use [`json_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to parse it.

```js
const IDs = [1, 2, 3];

document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = `
  encodeURIComponent(',') = ${ encodeURIComponent(',') }
  decodeURIComponent('%2C') = ${ decodeURIComponent('%2C') }
  
  IDs.toString() = ${ IDs.toString() }
  encodeURIComponent(IDs.toString()) = ${ encodeURIComponent(IDs.toString()) }
  
  JSON.stringify(IDs) = ${ JSON.stringify(IDs) }
  encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(IDs)) = ${ encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(IDs)) }
`;

document.cookies = `productIds=${ JSON.stringify(IDs) }`;

console.log(document.cookies);
console.log(Array.isArray(JSON.parse(document.cookies.split('=')[1])));
```

```html
<pre id="content"></pre>
```